# Python script to remove lines found between 2 concrete strings

Tags: python

I have put together a script which reads a text file as below,

```
*NODE
100000,1144.,-447.2639,339.0315
100001,1144.,-454.7716,342.956
100003,1144.,-448.2677,343.6241
100004,1144.,-454.8527,338.5432
*ELEMENT, TYPE=C3D6
228888,103103,103111,106773,186164,186165,196339
228889,103111,103232,106773,186165,186184,196339
228890,106773,106911,106912,196339,196457,196453
```

and writes only

```
228888,103103,103111,106773,186164,186165,196339
228889,103111,103232,106773,186165,186184,196339
228890,106773,106911,106912,196339,196457,196453
```

but I actually want it to write

```
*ELEMENT, TYPE=C3D6
228888,103103,103111,106773,186164,186165,196339
228889,103111,103232,106773,186165,186184,196339
228890,106773,106911,106912,196339,196457,196453
```

below is the code that I wrote,

```
with open('shell.txt', 'r') as oldfile, open('new_shell.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if writing:
            if "*NODE" in line:
                writing = False
            else:
                newfile.write(line)
        elif "*ELEMENT" in line:
            writing = True
newfile.write
```

Comment: Then you just need to `.write` on the line that starts with `"*ELEMENT"`, surely?

Comment: In situations like this  play around with your conditionals. For example, place `newfile.write(line)` somewhere at the end of your conditionals and then tweak your code a bit.

Comment: just look into oldfile until you find `* ELEMENT`, then just write everything after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an additional `write(line)` when "*ELEMENT" is found in line.

```
# init conditions
writing = False

with open('shell.txt', 'r') as oldfile, open('new_shell.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if writing:
            if "*NODE" in line:
                writing = False
            else:
                newfile.write(line)
        elif "*ELEMENT" in line:
            newfile.write(line)
            writing = True

newfile.write
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('shell.txt', 'r') as oldfile, open('new_shell.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        if writing:
            if "*NODE" in line:
                writing = False
            else:
                newfile.write(line)
        elif "*ELEMENT" in line:
            newfile.write(line)
            writing = True
newfile.write
```

You were not writing the line which contains *ELEMENT. But I would suggest generally doing all of this using regex / a bit of shell scripting.